# execute the same test multiple times using [junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar]

Tags: junit5

I am using junit5 standalone platform launcher and I want to execute the same test class several times using the command line of junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar.

I tried repeating (as per junit5 documentation) `--select-class` argument, i.e:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar --select-class=com.pcbsys.nirvana.nJMS.JMSQueueTxSessionConsumerTest --select-class=com.pcbsys.nirvana.nJMS.JMSQueueTxSessionConsumerTest --include-engine=junit-vintage --include-engine=junit-jupiter -cp ...
```

This yields:

```
Test run finished after 67368 ms
[         3 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         3 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         1 containers failed     ]
[         1 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         1 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         1 tests failed          ]
```

I can see that the test is executed only once (it is a failing test).

I also tried

```
--select-iteration=class:com.pcbsys.nirvana.nJMS.JMSQueueTxSessionConsumerTest[2]
```

but this syntax aims at parametrized tests, so was not the right for me.

Any ideas what needs fixing?

Comment: That’s not possible using the CLI interface. It will always generate a single request per test engine. That means you have to tell the engine, eg via a Jupiter Repeated annotation.

Comment: @johanneslink, Unfortunately, this does not work for me, as it requires the user to modify the code each time such action is needed...

Comment: Then you’ll have to start the tests 3 times.

Comment: @johanneslink, you mean that I have to do 3 separate invitations of the CLI (as one invocation with multiple --select-class would not work)?

Comment: exactly. The platform API is not conceived for running the same tests multiple times.